# How to exclude pages in the menu without pageID?

Tags: menus

I am creating a single page site, that contains multiple sections. These sections are pages within WordPress.

I use the following loop to get all pages in `index.php` file.

```
<?php 
        $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
        $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
    ?>
    <?php if ($loop) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
        global $post;
        $slug = $post->post_name;
    ?>
    <section id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" class="slideshow">
        <div class="container">
           <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
           <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

To order the pages (sections) inside the index.php file, I use the `menu_order` loop parameter to position the sections (pages) depending on the menu order, as you can see in above code.

This is working correctly, but the problem starts here. Because the site contains multiple sections that represent a kind of advertising section, it should not display in the menu as a menu item.

Look for the visual I added to this question. Left is a sidebar that contains the menu items. If you click on a item, it scrolls to the right section (page) on the page.

I created the menu as follow:

```
<?php wp_page_menu( array(
       'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
       'menu_class'  => 'primary-menu',
       'exclude'     => '',
    )); 
?>
```

I can use `exclude` to exclude specific pages from the menu, but this should be hardcode. All sections (pages) that use the Template `parallax` should be exclude from the list of menu items. As you can see in the visual, *page 2* should be exclude from the menu, ONLY from the menu, the section should still visible on the page.

It would be great, if there is a way to exclude these pages from the menu, but still use the order of the menu to position these sections on the right place, the same as the other ones that are not containing ads. Only the items that are exclude, should not display in the list of menu items.

Good to know is that each "advertising" section has the class parallax. And also the template has the header name in it (see below).

So if there is a way to code a function that will exclude these sections with the class `parallax`, would be great. There is a way to exclude pages hardcoded by putting in the pageID, but I am searching for a way this will be automatically handled within WordPress, by looking for the class `parallax` or something else...

Header of the parallax template:

```
<?php

/*
    Template Name: Parallax
*/

?>
```

If there are questions, I would like to hear from you. Hope someone can help me out! Thanks in advance. Have a good evening!

[image]

Comment: You can also use this plugin to exclude it https://wordpress.org/plugins/exclude-pages-from-menu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclusion has to be based on something connected to the pages that is stored in the database. The only thing template-related stored in the database is the filename of your Parallax template, which is stored in post meta under the key `_wp_page_template`. You could query for pages that either don't have the key `_wp_page_template`, or if it does have the key, that it doesn't equal whatever the filename of the template file is.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'fields'          => 'ids',
    'meta_query'      => array(
        'relation'    => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => '_wp_page_template',
            'value'   => 'templates/parallax.php',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_wp_page_template',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
```

You can then use the results of this query to build your own menu rather than using `wp_page_menu`. This will be more efficient in terms of number of queries, compared to the other option below...

EDIT - Another option is to query for all pages with the Parallax template. You can then use the results of this query to exclude those pages from `wp_page_menu`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'fields'          => 'ids',
    'meta_query'      => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wp_page_template',
            'value'   => 'templates/parallax.php',
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    ),
);

$pages_to_exclude = new WP_Query( $args );

wp_page_menu( array(
   'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
   'menu_class'  => 'primary-menu',
   'exclude'     => implode( ',', $pages_to_exclude->posts ),
));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks like to work, but the only thing is that this will work for which page is showed, am I right? What I am searching for is, the way to exclude only the menu item in the menu if the item has the page template parallax, but it should still display the page. So all pages should be visible, only the ones with a custom template parallax should not appears in the menu item list.

Comment: It excludes all pages with the parallax template, the page currently being viewed is irrelevant. See the [Custom Fields section for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for more details about meta queries.

Comment: Hmm this is not working as expect, because this array of arguments is used for the loop to walk through al pages. That is working correct, only what I want is to doesn't show the sections inside the menu.

Comment: Did you change `parallax.php` to the filename of your template file?

Comment: Yes, but your arg array should be added to the page loop, am I right? And `parallax.php` is saved in a folder `templates`.

Comment: Then it should be `templates/parallax.php`. It should replace the `$args =` line in your code.

Comment: whatever loop you are using to display a menu of pages.

Comment: well how are you generating the menu? the code is for the menu, not for the display of sections.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Thank you Milo. This is working, only how is the order of the menu items determined? Because the order of how I position the items in Appearance > Menu is not the same.. Is there also a way to exclude it for `wp_nav_menu` so the customer can manage the order of the sections with the Menu order?

Comment: `menu_order` is based on the Order field under Page attributes when editing a page. You could exclude pages from a nav menu with the `wp_nav_menu_items` filter.

Comment: Is there a possibility to make an example of the `wp_nav_menu_items `, like the previous ones. You would help me immensely and that's really where I have been looking for.

Comment: maybe later, I don't have time to write and test it. if you search around you'll probably find questions regarding how the filter works.

Comment: Okay, no problem. I will looking for it on the internet. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Still get stuck with the `wp_nav_menu_items`. If you have some time to help me out, would be absolute great.